# Как сделать коротко массив из функций. (массив, состоящий из функций) js?

Tags: javascript

1. Имею функции: foo(){} , foo1(){}, foo2(){}, foo3(){}.
2. Теперь напиши отрады.
3. Нужно чтобы стал массив var fooGeneral = [4] из функций чтобы
4. {foo(),foo1(),foo2(),foo3()},
5. чтобы вызвать функции как нибудь так fooGeneral[0] ->>>>>
6. и вуаля вызывается функция foo().
7. в java я этот трюк уже делал, а вот как мне сделать это в js

Comment: {foo(),foo1(),foo2(),foo3()} -> [foo(),foo1(),foo2(),foo3()]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массив из уже выше определенных функций:
let fooBraArr = [foo,foo1,foo2,foo3];

```
fooBraArr[0]() вызов
```

Объект с определением в нем:
let fooBraObj = {
 foo(){},
 foo1(){},
 foo2(){},
 foo3(){},
}

```
fooBraObj.foo3() вызов
```

Comment: !!! А так прокатит? `let fooBraObj={ foo0(), foo1(), foo2(), foo3()}`    ???  И вот еще как добавить или удалить новую функуию?  What's say you? А если нужно передать в функцию аргумент, то как это сделать скажем `foool(var i,var 2){ } `

Comment: Нет ))
let fooBraObj={ foo0(), foo1(), foo2(), foo3()} - тут функции вызовутся сразу! и в объект попадет результат их работы, если они его возвращают или будет ошибка

Comment: А можно, да, а можно, сделать push функций. т.е. добавлять новые функции... по методу push. Объясню так
`fooBraObj.push(foo4(){})` And now Harry Pota:
`fooBraArr[5]()` и вуаля: теперь вызывается вновь добавленная функция...

Answer (score 2):

Могём.

```js
function A0(param1) {
  console.log("first function", param1);
}

function A1() {
  console.log("second function");
}

let A = [ A0, A1 ];

A[0](123);
A[1]();
```

```js
let A = [ 
  function (param1) {
    console.log("first function", param1);
  }, 
  function () {
    console.log("second function");
  }
];

A.push(function(param2) {
  console.log("pushed function", param2);
});

A[0](123);
A[1]();
A[2]('abc');
```

Comment: Игоречек, а как передать переменную из массива `A[1]()` в функцию т.е. `A[1]("My Var")` How to do that?

Comment: Спасибо Вам присуждается 100 очков Гриффендорф.(из отряда Пфндуй.) А может быть разделить как нибудь очки, а то у Вас и так много. С верхним пользователем. Я не из корыстных заблуждений , а чисто из тактики логики.

Comment: @ArthurAlunts Насколько я знаю, не существует механизма деления "награды" на несколько человек.

Comment: Тогда награда тебе. Как говорил Агент Смидт из матрицы: "Ещё, ещё, ещё!!!"

Comment: @ArthurAlunts Спасибо.

Comment: Игорь у тебя Facebook есть?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts нет

Comment: а есть у тебя какие-нибудь контакты? Как связаться с пользователями, кроме чата???